# Update a plot dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot

I have the code below in a jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []


for i in range(10): 
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i**2)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
```

How do I update the scatter plot such that as the `x` and `y` list grows, the points on the plot increase too? Note I only want one graph and not 10.

Comment: the `plt.scatter` should be outside the loop. so it's only plotted when the lists are fully populated. or you mean that you want an animation where a new point is added for example every second?

Comment: I want an animation where the plot updates as the list grows in size. It does not have to be an animation however, it can plot the current list, clear the plot and then plot the new updated list.

Comment: then take a look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/animations.html

Comment: Can you code up an example and show me please.

Comment: Sorry we are not a free coding service, but in the link I posted you have examples. You just need to take this examples and adapt them to your needs.

Comment: Beyond the excellent advice from Sembei, there's a lot of examples in Stackoverflow as well. If you look around with good search terms you would probably have a more developed example than you have included here. For finding an example that builds as it runs, you can see some of the early examples if you go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder) and click `launch binder` and work through the examples I have there of various animations strategies. You step through running the cells there.